# $e^{-c\sin \theta}$ integral evaluation

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the following integral:
$$
I=\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}d\theta \, e^{-c \sin \theta},
$$
for some generic constant $c$ — any ideas?

Comment: $\underset{n\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{n \left(1-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} c n\right)^{1/n} \left(-2+\sqrt{3} c n\right)
   F_1\left(1+\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};2+\frac{1}{n};\frac{2-\sqrt{3} c n}{2+2 c n},\frac{-2+\sqrt{3} c n}{-2+2 c n}\right)}{(1+n)
   \sqrt{-1+c^2 n^2}}+\frac{2 (1-c n)^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{n};\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{n};-1+\frac{2}{1+c n}\right)}{\sqrt{-1+c^2 n^2} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$ where `F1` is AppellF1 function and `2F1` hypergeometric function

Comment: Thanks Mariusz, that's an interesting result, is that the simplest form you have managed to bring it to? Where did result this come from?

Comment: $\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}(1-n x)^{1/n}=e^{-x}$ and $\underset{n\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\int_{\frac{\pi }{3}}^{\frac{2 \pi }{3}} (1-c n \sin (x))^{1/n} \, dx$.Simple form you can try  to managed.
I do not have time for it to simplifying.

Comment: ah yes, i see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Using the Taylor development of the exponential,

$$I(c)=2\int_0^{\pi/6}e^{-c\cos\theta}d\theta=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \left[\int_0^{\pi/6}\cos^{k}\theta\,d\theta\right]\frac{c^{k}}{k!}.$$

The integrals can be computed using the binomial development of $(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^{k}$ and will result in a linear combination of binomial numbers. (WA gives an expression in terms of semi-factorials and an hypergeometric function.)

It is also possible to develop directly in terms of $\theta$ rather than $\cos\theta$. Probably equally difficult.

Comment: thanks for that, i managed to obtain a series representation but didn’t find it very enlightening , and was hoping that either the sum can be carried out or that the result (a closed form expression with no remaining sums to do) can be obtained by other means

Comment: @Wakabaloola: chances are high that you can drop the idea...

Comment: yes that may be true, but I thought it was worth posting here in case somebody comes up with a bright idea